# What is the difference between upload() and save() for storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to figure out how to upload images to firestore using Google Cloud Functions, and I see there are upload() and save() methods. I haven't been able to figure out the difference between them and when you should use one or the other. Can you tell me when each method is appropriate to use to upload/save an image to Firestore using Google Cloud Functions?

Example

```
await bucket.upload({destination, contentType})

await bucket.file().save()
```

Comment: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save vs https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload look at the parameters

Comment: Seems to me you could just pick the one that works best for your use case. Sometimes APIs provide more than one way of doing something as a convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Doug Stevenson:

> Seems to me you could just pick the one that works best for your use case. Sometimes APIs provide more than one way of doing something as a convenience.

---

As mentioned by @epascarello:

> googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save vs googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload look at the parameters

You may check the parameters difference in this link: [Save](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save) vs [Upload](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload)

---

The `save()` function is used when you already have the file data in memory and want to store it directly in Cloud Storage, whereas the `upload()` method is often used when you want to move a file from your local system or server to Cloud Storage. Again, it is best to choose that works best for your use case.